# How to fill data for missing months for more than 1 year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a report which displays month wise data from project start till the current month for a set of projects. When a project does not have data for few months it is not getting displayed.

I need to display the missing month rows for each project and show 0 for those rows.

There can be 2 or more projects (like 100 projects) for which the report is generated.The project start can be from earlier years like 2014 also.
Suppose the current month is Apr 2016.Then the report needs to display data from 201401 till 201604. In the example below i am using the project start month as 201512.

All the list of Months is stored in a Months table which contains all the months. The project start month (201512 and current month 201604 is passed to the storedprocedure as parameters)

At present the report looks like this

```
=====================================
|ProjectNo | Period | Billing | WIP  |
======================================
|000123    |201512  | 100      | 75  |  
|          |201601  | 200      | 100 | 
--------------------------------------
|000145    |201512  | 100      | 75  |
|          |201601  | 200      | 100 |
|          |201602  | 250      | 110 |    
|          |201604  | 550      | 110 |
======================================
```

The dataset returned looks like this (lets call the resultset as ProjectReportData)

```
=====================================
|ProjectNo | Period | Billing | WIP  |
======================================
|000123    |201512  | 100      | 75  |  
|000123    |201601  | 200      | 100 | 
|000145    |201512  | 100      | 75  |
|000145    |201601  | 200      | 100 |
|000145    |201602  | 250      | 110 |    
|000145    |201604  | 550      | 110 |
======================================
```

As you can see the 201602,201603 and 201604 are missing for Project No 000123.
For Project No 000145 , 201603 month is missing.

The expected output is like this

```
=====================================
|ProjectNo | Period | Billing | WIP  |
======================================
|000123    |201512  | 100      | 75  |  
|          |201601  | 200      | 100 |
|          |201602  | 0        | 0   |
|          |201603  | 0        | 0   |
|          |201604  | 250      | 110 |  
--------------------------------------
|000145    |201512  | 100      | 75  |
|          |201601  | 200      | 100 |
|          |201602  | 250      | 110 | 
|          |201603  | 0        | 0   |   
|          |201604  | 550      | 110 |
======================================
```

I tried doing a right join the ProjectReportData with the Months table,
this will fill the missing months.

```
|ProjectNo | Period | Billing | WIP  |
======================================
|000123    |201512  | 100      | 75  | 
|000123    |201601  | 200      | 100 | 
|NULL      |201602  | NULL     | NULL|
|NULL      |201603  | NULL     | NULL| 
|NULL      |201604  | NULL     | NULL|  
|000145    |201512  | 100      | 75  |
|000145    |201601  | 200      | 100 |
|000145    |201602  | 250      | 110 | 
|NULL      |201603  | NULL     | NULL|    
|000145    |201604  | 550      | 110 |
======================================
```

But i need the ProjectNo also to be filled instead of NULL.

How can i acheive this. Please suggest.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: can you show your right join?

Comment: please add the sql you are using

Comment: This is a good reason to have a calendar table in your database.

Comment: Hi i am using sql server 2012. The Months table is the calendar table...It contains the months in the form of 201601 for Jan 2016, 201602 for Feb 2016 etc..it is having months from 2014 onwards

Comment: This the right join i am using                                                                     select M.Period,ProjectNo,Billing,WIP from ProjectReportData PRD
right join Months M on M.period=PRD.period ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Projects table in your database:

```
select ProjectNo, Period, IsNull(wip, 0) wip , IsNull(billing, 0) billing
from Projects d1
outer apply (
    select m.*,d2.wip, d2.billing
    from Months m
    left join ProjectReportData d2 on m.Period = d2.Period and d2.ProjectNo=d1.ProjectNo
) mm
order by 1, 2 desc
```

If you don't have a Projects table in your database:

```
select ProjectNo, Period, IsNull(wip, 0) wip , IsNull(billing, 0) billing
from (
    select distinct ProjectNo
    from ProjectReportData 
) d1
outer apply (
    select m.*,d2.wip, d2.billing
    from Months m
    left join ProjectReportData d2 on m.Period = d2.Period and d2.ProjectNo=d1.ProjectNo
) mm
order by 1, 2 desc
```

Comment: My vote is not visible publicly because i do not have enough points to upvote

Answer (score 0):

Put a cross join in a CTE:

```
with Projects as
(
select distinct ProjectNumber
from ProjectReportData 
)
, Periods as
(
select p.ProjectNumber, c.Period
from Projects p
cross join CalendarTable c
)
select a.*, b.Billing, b.WIP
from Periods a
left join ProjectReportData b
  on a.ProjectNumber = b.ProjectNumber
```